# Initialising a datetime64 RingBuffer

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a slightly modified implementation of [mtambos/ring_buffer](https://gist.github.com/mtambos/aa435461084b5c0025d1)'s ring buffer. I want to initialise it with `datetime64` values. I can get the last minute like so:

```
    self.x = RingBuffer(
        np.array([
            np.datetime64('now') - np.timedelta64(seconds=i)
            for i in range(60)
        ]))
    self.y = RingBuffer(np.zeros(60))
```

However, there is no data for that last minute. I would like to have some [missing value `np.NA`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/missing-data.html) in `self.x` but this [NEP](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/missing-data.html) seems to have lead no where. Every second (say), a new real value (coming from some sensor) will be added to `self.y` and a current time stamp will be added to `self.x`.

*How can I initialise `self.x` with missing values?*

This data is eventually plotted via `MatPlotLib`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), this is actually trivial:

```
    self.x = RingBuffer(
        ma.array([
            now - np.timedelta64(datetime.timedelta(microseconds=i))
            for i in range(self._seconds)
        ], mask=self._seconds*[True]))
    self.y = RingBuffer(ma.zeros(self._seconds),
                        mask=self._seconds*[True])
```

Where `class RingBuffer(ma.MaskedArray)`. To plot the data, one needs to do this:

```
        self.plt.set_xdata(self.x.compressed())
        self.plt.set_ydata(self.y.compressed())
```